# iPad: How to not allow a page to be resized by an element being dragged on the edges?

Tags: jquery, ipad, drag, scale

I have my page all set up perfectly and the height & width's are all working great. But I have a draggable element and if you drag it to the side/corner of the page, it starts shrinking the whole page instead of cutting off the element on the edge. The element is always visible where ever your dragging, its just the rest of the page shrinks.

I just want it to stay the same size as it is right now, and have the draggable element get cut off at the edge if a user drags it there.
Anyway to do/fix this?

I am using this in my meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, maximum-scale=1.7, width=device-width" />
```

Maybe the width=device-width has something to do with it?

Comment: Do you have the page visible on any server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try `body { overflow:hidden; }` in your CSS (but I have not tested this).

Comment: This worked for the sides but didn't seem to work if you dragged it to the corner for some reason...

I did find another way though, I just had to put minimum-scale=1.0 into the meta tag. 

Thanks for your help :) 
Im marking your answer as right since your the only one who actually answered!